# SSO Metadata and C# MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, single-sign-on, saml

I am new to SSO and am trying to get it working between my org and another company. The way I understand it, is that I post credential data to their internet exposed SSO server, and they would post data back to my C# MVC web app with the data about the user, if successful.

However the other org asked for a SAML xml metadata file, which I provided. He then returned his own metadata file.

I am unsure about why he asked for a file and also provided his own. What am I to do with the metadata file in my MVC web app? Are they trying to establish a trust between our AD servers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Yuriy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are trying to set up a SAML2 based single sign on solution. SAML2 basically works by you redirecting the user to the Idp with an encoded AuthnRequest in the URL. The user enters credentials at the idp (your app will never see the actual credentials) and then posts an encoded SAML2 Response to your app. Validating that correctly is non trivial. You need to first make a correct validation of the XML Signature (including checking references that most ppl forget) and then validate all the conditions in the assertion.*

The metadata is a way to describe what URLs each party expects messages to be sent to, how the messages should be encoded (what bindings to use), what certificates that are used to sign messages etc. Basically a standardized summary of the required configuration parameters.

Don't do this on your own. It's much more complex than expected. I've tried and learnt the hard way. Use a ready-made library for SAML2. Mine is called Kentor.AuthServices and is available on GitHub/Nuget, there are other open source and commercial options too.

*) There are variations of this, what I've described here is the most common flow with an AuthnRequest over the HTTP Redirect binding followed by a plain SamlResponse over the HTTP POST binding.